# Bash - Deleting the same rows in two CSV files

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have two CSV files - nodes.csv and edges.csv - where the columns are tab delimited. I've deleted certain rows in nodes.csv using

```
awk -F'\t' -i inplace '($3 != "Symbol")' nodes.csv
```

How do I delete the corresponding rows in edges.csv?

For example, in nodes.csv, I have:

```
ANR 35755   ParameterType   uint32_t
CYP 35756   Identifier      status
ANR 35757   CFGEntryNode    ENTRY
ANR 35758   CFGExitNode     EXIT
ANR 35759   Symbol          * host
CYP 35760   Symbol          * irq_status_bits
ANR 35761   Symbol          irq_status_bits
```

And in edges.csv, I have:

```
35738   35758   FLOWS_TO
35689   35759   USE
35701   35759   USE
35727   35760   USE
35734   35760   USE
35727   35761   USE
35735   35761   USE
```

I need to delete rows 5,6,7 in `nodes.csv` because column 3 has the value symbol. How do I remove rows 5,6,7 in `edges.csv`?

Output:
`nodes.csv`

```
ANR 35755   ParameterType   uint32_t
CYP 35756   Identifier      status
ANR 35757   CFGEntryNode    ENTRY
ANR 35758   CFGExitNode     EXIT
```

`edges.csv`:

```
35738   35758   FLOWS_TO
35689   35759   USE
35701   35759   USE
35727   35760   USE
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: How to you define `corresponding rows`?

Comment: Please show example lines from edges.csv for lines you want to keep and you want to delete.

Comment: I updated my question, if it helps!

Comment: Without an example of `edges.csv` and a precise definition of what you want to remove from it, this question is pretty vague.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, does it matter what there is in `edges` if they want to remove lines by their number...

Comment: I'm very sorry, I didn't realize the question was vague. I've fixed it now, I hope it's okay!

Comment: Thanks that's much better.

Comment: @ilkkachu. The recent edits have made the question clear. It certainly wasn't before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F'\t' -i inplace 'NR==FNR{if ($3 != "Symbol") a[NR]} FNR in a' nodes.csv edges.csv
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question! And editing my answer. If you don't mind, could you please explain what the script is doing?

Comment: It's populating an array `a[]` with the "good" line numbers by checking the contents of the first file and then only printing out lines with those line numbers (`FNR in a`) from both files.